# Using -> operator on arrays

Tags: c++

I just discovered this weird syntax by accident. You can actually use operator-> on arrays.

```
struct Foo
{
    void bar() { }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo[3] = { Foo(), Foo(), Foo() };
    foo->bar();
}
```

I thought operator-> was only for pointers to objects, and I don't see any pointers in this code. Even if there were pointers, they'd be dangling pointers because of the Foo temporaries. What makes this possible?

Comment: `foo` decays to a pointer to its first element. And that points to a valid object. There are no dangling pointers in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are allowed to decay to pointers, and these point to the first element of the array. So for example, you can do this:

```
void bar(int*) {}

int a[42] = {};
int* b = a;      // a decayed to int*, got assigned to b
bar(a);          // a decayed to int* to match bar parameter type
```

In your example, `foo` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array `foo` when you apply the `->` operator. The following two are equivalent:

```
foo->bar();
(&foo[0])->bar();
```

Concerning the validity of the object pointed at, an array such as

```
Foo foo[3];
```

always contains 3 default initialized `Foo` objects. What you have done is initialize them explicitly, but that doesn't change anything. The array contains copies of the objects you used to initialize its elements.

Answer (score 3):

> You can actually use `operator->` on arrays.

Yes, the standard *array-to-pointer* conversion means that an expression of array type, like `foo`, can decay to a pointer to the first array element if it's used in a context where a pointer is expected.

> I thought operator-> was only for pointers to objects

It's for any type that's convertible to an object pointer - including an array - and for any class type that it's overloaded for.

> Even if there were pointers, they'd be dangling pointers because of the `Foo` temporaries.

No, `foo` is not a temporary, and neither are the elements it contains. You initialised them by copying temporaries, but the copies in the array last as long as the array itself.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought operator-> was only for pointers to objects, and I don't see any pointers in this code.

An array decays to pointer when used in an expression like you have.

> Even if there were pointers, they'd be dangling pointers because of the Foo temporaries. What makes this possible?

The line

```
 Foo foo[3] = { Foo(), Foo(), Foo() }
```

fills `foo` with three valid objects, not temporaries.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html

§ 4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array]

> <sup>1</sup> An lvalue or rvalue of type `array of N T` or `array of unknown
>   bound of T` can be converted to an rvalue of type `pointer to T.`
>   The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You declare an array of 3 `Foo` instances. You initialize the array by creating 3 instances with `{ Foo(), Foo(), Foo() }` and they are not moved or copied into place in the array, they are actually created there, so no temporaries exist.